# LINQ to SQL and Dynamics CRM 2011 data views and paging VERY SLOW

Tags: performance, linq-to-sql, pagination, dynamics-crm

I am at a loss as the best way to access Dynamics CRM 2011 data and with custom search criteria. I am porting a website that used a contacts database and forms security. The contacts have been moved into Dynamics CRM 2011, so I am using the CRM 2011 SDK and early binding to connect to the CRM to retrieve the data. I have used the code generation tool, CrmSvcUtil.exe.
I am using LINQ to build a query that selects from the contact set into the ContactViewDefault class:

```
IQueryable<ContactViewDefault> query = from c in orgContext.ContactSet
                                                select new ContactViewDefault
                                                {
                                                    Username = c.EMailAddress1 ?? "",
                                                    Title = c.Salutation ?? "",
                                                    Firstname = c.FirstName ?? "",
                                                    Lastname = c.LastName ?? "",
                                                    Organisation = "",
                                                    Position = c.JobTitle ?? "",
                                                    Phone = c.Telephone1 ?? "",
                                                    Mobile = c.MobilePhone ?? "",
                                                };

PagedDataSource pagedData = new PagedDataSource();
        pagedData.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        pagedData.AllowPaging = true;
        pagedData.PageSize = 10;
        pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = 1;
        pagedData.DataSource = query;
```

If I then databind to "Username"

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Username")%>
```

I get the error: 'ContactViewDefault' does not contain a property with the name 'Username'.
Also, calling query.Count() is not supported.

I then tried the CopyToDataTable code (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx ) to copy to a data table and then use my existing repeaters and paging.
The problem is that the code IS VERY SLOW. It can take about 3 minutes to fill the datatable. There are 7000 records in the table.

I have tried custom paging as described in http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345,

```
query.OrderBy(c => c.Username);
query.Take(10);
query.Skip(0);
```

to select the first 10 records, but it still takes over 20 seconds to fill a basic repeater.
By comparison, the original code can select all the data into the paged data source and display the first page in less that a second.

So I am having several issues and I am asking if I am approaching this correctly.
I have many more pages to convert with more complex queries and joins, so I want to get started on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are retrieving all contacts, create 7000 ContactViewDefault
objects and page through them. Try retrieving 10 contacts (with paging) before converting them to ContactViewDefault.

Comment: The issue was that the CRM Org Context did not support all the features and was also very fat. I did numerous performance tests and using the generated CRM Org Context became unworkable.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a LINQ data context to the SQL views and used this for all selects. These were over 200 times faster in some cases. I did use the CRM Org Context for all inserts, updates and deletes to maintain the database integrity. These are small operations, and although still slow, they are workable. Overall my conclusion is that the CRM is very bandwidth hungry which effects the performance.

Answer (score 0):

arch answer is right. You try to convert all the data into ContactViewDefault. If you want, you can try to use this code

```
IQueryable<ContactViewDefault> query = (from c in orgContext.ContactSet
                                            select a).AsQuerayable();
var data = (from c in query.Take(10)
            select new ContactViewDefault
                                            {
                                                Username = c.EMailAddress1 ?? "",
                                                Title = c.Salutation ?? "",
                                                Firstname = c.FirstName ?? "",
                                                Lastname = c.LastName ?? "",
                                                Organisation = "",
                                                Position = c.JobTitle ?? "",
                                                Phone = c.Telephone1 ?? "",
                                                Mobile = c.MobilePhone ?? "",
                                            }).ToList();
```

Sure the performance not going down if you try to use this sample. I'm pretty agree that Linq to SQL in CRM is not good enough. But this basic sure very important to know.